# Remote shared objects with socket server and multiplayer games

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, air, multiplayer

Developing a multiplayer AIR based Andoid game and need to save high scores. I was considering using local shared objects to save the scores on the server app but after reading the documentation was wondering if remote shared objects might also work.

Can anyone tell me if I MUST use flash media server to use remote shared objects?

Perhaps even my choice of the socket server class is the wrong approach.

Comment: For flash you might look into using a multiplayer game engine like playerio or smartfoxserver. Smartfox is my favourite.

Answer (score 0):

What are you using to develop the AIR game? I am using Flash Professional with a code editor separate for as3. You do not need to use flash media server.

I am using Electroserver through Amazon EC2 cloud servers. Electroserver basically builds into as3 the shell of a multiplayer game(rooms, zones, message system).

Socket servers are the way to go though. Electroserver is socket server too.

Comment: Thanks. Having a problem though getting a socket connection over wifi. Can you suggest any troubleshooting steps?